# Alternate text colour for each line of paragraph

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the text colour on alternate lines of a paragraph. The problem is, the number of lines in a paragraph will depend on things like screen size. Is there a way in CSS where I can have alternate text colours for each line inside a `<p>` tag?

For example, in the following code

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vel metus sapien. Duis eleifend justo eu enim venenatis, quis malesuada eros rhoncus. Sed id orci sed nulla ultrices lobortis. Nam ultricies nibh dictum odio posuere porttitor. Vivamus vitae diam felis. Duis dapibus eget velit id tempor. Integer tristique viverra lorem sit amet congue. Suspendisse vitae ex condimentum, volutpat nisi eu, cursus dolor. Curabitur suscipit hendrerit semper. Vestibulum egestas lorem vitae aliquet egestas. Nulla non faucibus velit, sit amet sagittis velit. Nulla fringilla efficitur erat, sed porttitor mi fringilla non. Phasellus dictum gravida ligula at elementum. Phasellus nec dui suscipit, mollis turpis eu, posuere erat.</p>
```

Each line of text should be an alternate colour **regardless of which words are actually on which lines** (which will obviously depend on the screen size).

My first instinct was to try and calculate the number of lines based on screen size, but then I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: @Zak The post, as is, is too broad at present. It lacks both research attempts and a [mcve]. The OP has not read [ask]. However if you can edit the post and make it cleaner, (and at the same time not drastically changing the meaning), then I'll certainly open the post.

Comment: @BhargavRao I've submitted an edit which includes a code example. I think it is a great question otherwise which can generate interesting answers, so if that is the only issue, I'd be grateful if you could reopen it.

Comment: I've reopened the post, But @dalold, it'd be great if you could try out *My first instinct was to try and calculate the number of lines based on screen size* and post your attempts here.

Comment: Take a look at https://codepen.io/jnowland/details/AifjK

Comment: @deathangel908 I like your solution but you're answering a slightly different question as you've alternated the background colour, not the text colour. Also, the question said it should be done with CSS, you've used JavaScript as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice question! For a CSS only implementation of this, you can use the magic of `webkit-background-clip`, along with a gradient.

**You can try out my solution at https://jsfiddle.net/kavot054/, I've also put the HTML and CSS code for it below.**

Notice the relationship between the `line-height` of the text and the gradient; if you were to change the font for example, you would need to update both of these.

It is also worth noting that the `webkit-background-clip` only works on webkit browsers, so this is something to be wary of when thinking about your site's accessibility.

```css
p {
  line-height: 30px;
  background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(red, red 30px, blue 30px, blue 60px);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vel metus sapien. Duis eleifend justo eu enim venenatis, quis malesuada eros rhoncus. Sed id orci sed nulla ultrices lobortis. Nam ultricies nibh dictum odio posuere porttitor. Vivamus vitae diam felis. Duis dapibus eget velit id tempor. Integer tristique viverra lorem sit amet congue. Suspendisse vitae ex condimentum, volutpat nisi eu, cursus dolor. Curabitur suscipit hendrerit semper. Vestibulum egestas lorem vitae aliquet egestas.
  Nulla non faucibus velit, sit amet sagittis velit. Nulla fringilla efficitur erat, sed porttitor mi fringilla non. Phasellus dictum gravida ligula at elementum. Phasellus nec dui suscipit, mollis turpis eu, posuere erat.</p>
```